# std::vector pointer

Tags: c++, stl

I have one question in mind, what if i have a STL vector, I can write like

```
std::vector<int> *p;
```

But I am not able to decide if I will use it in any situation? Also what will happen to pointer p in this case, if I resize the vector which is being pointer by p?

I may sound stupid here but these questions just came in mind, and I am able to compile the thing `std::vector<int> *p` in g++.

Comment: I believe you are confusing the pointer to the vector to a pointer to the elements of the vector. This is quite understandable since the way C and C++ treat native arrays encourages this confusion. But a pointer to a vector has nothing to do with its elements, unlike a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 3):

By saying:

```
std::vector *p;
```

You are declaring a pointer to a Vector. Now, you would need to assign memory location to hold memory content of the Vector Object, not the individual elements. After that, you are free to Add,Remove,Delete and Update individual elements according to your wish.

As for resizing the vector, nothing will happen to the memory p is referring to, only the content of that memory related to the Vector object will change.

One use of such structure is to have dynamic array of Vectors. Say you need to maintain an Adjacency list of Nodes, but you are not sure in advance as to how many Nodes will come up, until run time.

Comment: I'd say instead of a dynamic array of vectors you could just use a vector of vectors. There is almost no reason (actually, I can't think of one) to declare a vector this way in modern C++ (think smart-pointers).

Comment: @Shamim, so I assume that in the case of resizing the vector, my pointer p still be valid( even internal memory location would be changed for vector during resize operation)?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Yes, I agree with you. Vector of Vectors eliminate the need for having a pointer. So, using a Pointer in this way will be a overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers to a vector in case that you want to choose one specific vector from many at runtime, i. e. you want to chose it dynamically.

Regarding the "resize" question: As [Are vector pointers affected by resize()?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/57258/) states, the pointer to the vector itself is valid as long the vector exists. But pointers to elements of the vector may change. For example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int> *p;
p = &v; // Does not change

int *pe;
pe = &v[0]; // May change
```